# C# linq how to build expandoobjects into a list?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, enumerable

I am trying to select expandoobjects (`qs_ll[0][0]`) from `List<dynamic>` and build them into a new list.

I have managed to use `GetRange()` and `.concat()` to select and combine sublists. It does work, but it is rather verbose. I would fancy the index method as it looks tidy.

I currently trying like `Enumerable.Concat(qs_ll[0][0],qs_ll[0][1])`. However, the result turn out to be a series of objects [column name,value] and it does not have `ToList()`. I would like it keep the structure of expandoobjects{value1,value2,value3,...}.

I assume it can be done with the use of certain functions.

Comment: can you show a little more about the use case/user story, i.e. why  you want those?

Comment: @JWP As I mentioned, I have tried this straightforward .ToList() method and it doesn't work out, saying cannot transform List<object> to List<dynamic>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I find the most straightforward way by myself (it is just there all the time).

`new List<dynamic>{qs_ll[0][0], qs_ll[0][1]};`

I have been thinking of it in a merging lists manner, forgetting the fact that those variables are just elements which would just build a list. To build elements into a list, how could it be done easier by just `new List<>{ele1,ele2,...};`?..

Comment: does `new List<>{ele1,ele2,...}` compiles?

Comment: @LeiYang Hi, it is just a generalizable example. I think you can see that the data type will be in <>. If you refer to the complete instantiation code, just look at the first one I put.